# Multiple github accounts error

Tags: git, github, command-line-interface

I keep getting an "ERROR: Permission to techjems17/beerholic-pokemon.git denied to JoSmith17. fatal: Could not read from remote repository" I have already created and added a SSH key to my github account, and have even been able to push and some code to it. After I had turned off my computer and then tried changing my code and pushing again I get this error. For some reason it is still attaching to my old github account and I do not know how to stop it and change it permanently to my new one. I have tried configuring the user name and email as well.

Comment: Are you using an SSH URL (`git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git`) or an HTTP URL (`https://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git`)? Your SSH key will only be used in the former case.

Comment: I am using the SSH URL.

Comment: Just to note; perhaps it'll help avoid a headache: The configured user name and e-mail are only meta data for commits and have nothing to do with authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Okay after lots of research and trying multiple things. I only had to do the fallowing:
1. Be inside the repository.
2. type `eval "$(ssh-add -s)"`
3. type `ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa_(whatever else you added to SSH key)`
4. `git push`
This is what ended up working for me!